# Power BI - Represent Data from Excel in the same format as the input

Tags: powerbi

The input data from my excel source is shown here:

[image: Input Excel file.]

When I am creating a table report in Power BI, this how the data set is showing up.

[image: The output format in Power BI right now]

How do I set up the linkage between the Name and Skills columns so that my Power BI report can resemble the input source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want to fill in those blank rows so that your data table looks like this

[image: Data Table]

Luckily, you can do this fairly easily in the query editor by replacing empty string rows with null and then using Transform > Fill Down to duplicate the last non-null value.

[image: Fill Down command]

Here's what the full M code might look like:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8spPVdJRcgwPVorViVYCMatKi1JhHHfPEDDTN7ECyAsO9IFJBOfll6flJGbDVYakFiWmJJYkgvkBiaU5IKOCw+EGOQcoxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Skill = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Skill", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Name"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Name"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

Once you have all your rows properly filled, then you can make a matrix visual the way you'd like. (You'll need to put both columns in the Row field and turn off Stepped layout in the Format pane under Row headers.)

[image: Stepped layout off]